# 'infinity' PostgreSQL date/time input not showing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-2, datetime

I have a PostgreSQL table with a date-type column populated either with proper dates (e.g. `2016-01-01`) or with PostgreSQL `infinity` [date/time input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE).

When I display the table in QGIS 2.14.11-1 (via DB Manager), the rows containing `infinity` values display `NULL` values instead (see last row on screenshot below).

[image]

Therefore, I'm unable to apply a rule-based style for these rows that remain impossible to select via the following rules (both rules return 0 selected feature):

```
"date" IS NULL
"date" = NULL
"date" = 'infinity'
```

Any idea on this issue and how I could deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

## Work around

You may be able to create a `VIEW` that wraps the table.

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS
SELECT 
  gid,
  insee,
  libelle,
  statut_date,
  CASE
    WHEN isfinite(fusion_Date)
    THEN fusion_date
    ELSE '3000-01-01'::date
  END AS fusion_date
FROM table;
```

## File a bug

- https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: Thanks @EvanCarroll! This is a good option but the best would be to be able to deal with `infinity` values within QGIS. I'm thinking about filing a bug then.

Comment: That's all you can do. I would guess this would be a *very* low priority bug. I don't think I've ever seen anyone store `infinity` in a table.. I would love to know what your use case is for it, just because this is the first time I've seen it. Even PostgreSQL ranges can't operate on infinity. It's like a value that just sits there so you can't compare to an upper-bound that you can store as another time.

Comment: See here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/149076/48623 for my need to use `infinity`.

Comment: @wiltomap that's bad advice. Do you want me to submit a new answer. ;)